# How to capture local time and store it in mysql table?

Tags: php, mysql, datetime

Im trying to capture the local time and store it into a mysql table. 
I read the "PHP manual" which says:

```
$today = date("H:i:s");   //  the result would be something like 17:16:18
```

But when I try it, the result is 00:00:00

So I tried

```
$today = date('Y/m/d');
```

And the result would be the correct todays date.

If I go to check what was stored on mysql I see this:

```
2013-11-14 00:00:00
```

So its capturing the date, but not the time. What am I doing wrong? How can I capture my local time?

Comment: Local to whom? Php returns time based on host time and timezone in php.ini. mysql uses its timezone conig. You're better off storing time in UTC and adjusting value to target tz.

Comment: @Anthony please tell me how, my eyes are already blood red from searching the internet and cant seem to find the way.

Comment: http://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.settimezone.php

Answer (score 1):

Just use MySQL's built in datetime functionality. [`NOW()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_now), [amongst others](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html), would work well here:

```
INSERT INTO tablename (datecol) VALUES (NOW());
```

Comment: Thanks it worked. But that´s not the local time. I tried to change the timezone using date_default_timezone_set but it does not change it. So Im stuck with the server timezone. Thats why I was avoiding using the timestamp default :-s

Answer (score 1):

Finally I have my answer. Thanks to @Anthony I was able to research on the right direction.

So the answer I was looking from you guys was:

First set the desired timezone:

```
date_default_timezone_set('America/Costa_Rica');
```

And then just capture the actual time

```
$actualtime=date("H:i", time());
```

Comment: And one more thing, in order to store this on mysql, if the field is a DateTime field, then use date("Y-m-d H:i:s", time()) format.